# RxJava Cannot get value in map

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm facing a problem when reading list of observables from ftp server.Here is my code:

```
public RxJavaProcessor<byte[], String> processor() {
        /*
         * return inputStream -> inputStream.map(data -> { logger.info("Got data = " +
         * data); return data; }).buffer(10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map(data ->
         * processData(data));
         */

        return inputStream -> inputStream.map(data -> {
            logger.info("Got data = " + data);
            return data;
        }).buffer(10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).collect(ByteArrayOutputStream::new, (bout, bytes) -> {
            bytes.forEach(byteItem -> {
                bout.write(byteItem, 0, byteItem.length);
            });
        }).map(bout -> {
            byte[] byteArray = bout.toByteArray();
            try {
                logger.info("byte array to string: " + new String(byteArray, "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return byteArray;
        }).map(data -> processData(data));
    }
```

If I put in log the byte array inside **collect** operator like this:

***logger.info("byte array to string: " + new String(byteItem, "UTF-8"))***. I see the result which is an input xml. But when I write in log inside **map** like shown in the piece of code above
**logger.info("byte array to string: " + new String(byteArray, "UTF-8"))**
.I don't see any result, so what is the problem ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `collect` requires a finite stream and it will only emit `bout` if its source has completed, thus the `map` won't get executed until then.

Comment: @akarnokd how I can resolve this issue  (how I can complete the source ?)? Could you show me an example please ?

Comment: Why are you batching byte arrays in the first place? What is and where does the input sequence come from? What is the expected output?

Comment: @akarnokd I get the bytes from xml deployed in ftp server as List<byte[]>.My problem is converting List<byte[]> to whole table byte[] and then processing them.

Comment: What is giving you that `List<byte[]>` and how? If it is an entire XML, you shoud already get a finite sequence of the input data.

Comment: @akarnokd exactly first it's just a byte[] at the begining but when I call buffer(10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) operator it transforms it to List<byte[]>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182022/discussion-between-mohamed-aoutir-and-akarnokd).